# How can I get a list of all Apache Beam metrics used in the pipeline?

Tags: java, apache-beam, dataflow

I am trying to get a complete exhaustive list of all metrics used in an Apache Beam Dataflow pipeline.

As I recall, after upgrading from the 1.x Java Dataflow SDK to the Apache Beam Java SDK (v2.5) we noticed that all the counters which never increase from 0 do not get reported.

I have this code to extract all the metrics from the PipelineResult, but if a Counter is never incremeted it is not listed.

```
public static ArrayList<String> getAggregationFields(PipelineResult pr) {
    MetricsFilter filter = MetricsFilter.builder().build();
    MetricQueryResults metricQueryResults = pr.metrics().queryMetrics(filter);

    Iterable<MetricResult<Long>> counters = metricQueryResults.getCounters();

    ArrayList<String> fieldNames = new ArrayList<>();
    for (MetricResult<Long> metricValue : counters) {
        fieldNames.add(metricValue.getName().getName());
    }
    return fieldNames;
}
```

In conclussion, **is it even possible to get a list of all counters?**

Answer (score 1):

The [docs for the queryMetrics method](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.9.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/metrics/MetricResults.html#queryMetrics-org.apache.beam.sdk.metrics.MetricsFilter-) hint that there are no guarantees about providing a result for a counter that is never incremented:

> Note that runners differ in their support for committed and attempted values.

For Dataflow in particular, the implementation of `DataflowMetrics#queryMetrics` makes it look unlikely you'd be able to know about counters that were never incremented. That method retrieves a list of `MetricUpdate`s and then proceeds to aggregate and filter. It would follow that a non-incremented counter would return no `MetricUpdate` instances and thus wouldn't appear in the query results.

I don't have much previous experience with Beam's metrics API, though, so I may not fully understand what's possible here.